# irrational inequality

Tags: calculus

Solve the set of all values of $x$ for which the given inequality is satisfied 
$x – 3 < \sqrt{(x^2 + 4x -5)}.$

Can't I solve this as following 
$$\begin{align} x - 3 < \sqrt{x^2 +4x -5} &\Rightarrow x^2 - 6x + 9 < x^2 + 4x -5 \\ &\Rightarrow
-10x < -14 \\ & \Rightarrow
 x > 7/5 \end{align}$$

Answer is different in my textbook.
What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does the ticket mean?

Comment: It's dangerous to square inequalities.  $-2<1$ but $4\not < 1$.    In your case, $x=-100$ clearly satisfies the original inequality, but not the squared version.

Comment: $x<\sqrt a$ is not the same as $x^2<a$! Try it with e.g. $a=9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it helps to know where $\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ is defined. Note that $$x^2+4x-5=x^2+4x+4-9=(x+2)^2-9=(x+2)^2-3^2,$$ so by the difference of squares formula $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v),$ we have $$x^2+4x-5=(x+2+3)(x+2-3)=(x+5)(x-1).$$ This will be negative for $-5<x<1,$ but non-negative otherwise, so the domain of $\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ is $(-\infty,-5]\cup[1,\infty).$

Now, since $\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ is a non-negative function on its entire domain, and since $x-3<0$ when $x<3,$ then we clearly have $x-3<\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ for $x\in(-\infty,-5]\cup[1,3).$ But what about when $x\in[3,\infty)?$ Well, in that case, we know that $x-3\ge 0,$ so that $x-3<\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ if and only if $(x-3)^2<x^2+4x-5.$ As you've already determined, this reduces to $x>\frac75,$ which is true for every $x\in[3,\infty).$ Thus, $x-3<\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}$ for all $x\in(-\infty,-5]\cup[1,\infty).$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

On the domain of validity ($B\ge 0$), one has
$$A<\sqrt{B}\iff (A<0)\enspace \text{ OR }\enspace (A\ge 0 \enspace\text{ and }\enspace  A^2<B).$$

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that if a< b it is not necessarily true that $a^2< b^2$.  For example, -3< -2 but 9> 4.